# Bash script to delete remote files based on local file matches

Tags: bash, unix, sftp

Here is a bash script I run locally:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

ls some_pattern_*.txt > deletion_list.txt
rm $(cat deletion_list.txt)
rm deletion_list.txt

exit 0
```

What it does is it looks for files that match a certain pattern, and outputs that list of files into a text file called `deletion_list.txt`. Then the script deletes all of the files specified in the text document, before finally deleting `deletion_list.txt` itself. This may sound really convoluted, but I have a reason for doing it this way.

Here is a slightly modified version I'm trying to run on a remote host via a `sftp` connection:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

sftp -i ~/.ssh/myprivatekey $username@$host <<-EOF
lcd /home/mydirectory
!ls some_pattern_*.txt > deletion_list.txt
rm $(cat deletion_list.txt)
!rm deletion_list.txt
EOF

exit 0
```

What this should do is:

1) Connect to the remote host using `sftp` (`ssh` is not enabled on the remote host, in case any answers suggest using `ssh` instead)

2) Change the local directory

3) Create a list of files to delete from the local directory we're in, and store `deletion_list.txt` locally in the same directory

4) Delete files from the remote host based on files in `deletion_list.txt` - the deletion happens remotely, the list of files to delete is local ( `deletion_list.txt` is created from files that are local, and the same files are then deleted from the remote host).

I am having an issue with step #4 specifically. I don't know how to delete the remote files feeding in from a local file.

EDIT:

As someone has pointed out, `cat` does not work during a SFTP session either.

Comment: `rm some_pattern_*.txt`?

Comment: Obligatory: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @KamilCuk There are remote files matching the pattern that I do NOT want to delete. Creating a list of files first to delete is part of my requirement, and that was specified in the question.

Comment: You said "I have a reason", but believe me, more often than not, "the reason" by whoever asks the question is a false assumption.

Comment: Then I do not understand. Do you create the list of files to remove before or after connecting to remote server?

Comment: Create based on local matches, then delete remotely, right?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Correct.

Comment: @KamilCuk I happen to do it after connecting, but in reality it doesn't matter. The local files do not change. My problem is I can't delete the remote files based on local matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `ssh` is not available, you will not be able to do `$(cat ...)`.

But you can create the `rm` commands locally and send them to the server:

```
find -printf 'rm %f\n' -name 'pattern' | \
   sftp -b - server:`pwd`
```

NOTE: you will probably need an extra layer to ensure correct quoting (e.g. what happens when filename contains space or newline?).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "send them to the server"? Is each individual `rm` command being sent to the server separately?

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh  $username@$host  "ls -1 | grep -v some_pattern_*.txt |  xargs rm"
```

https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs

xargs --> Converts pipeline input input argument for command

Comment: Again, just `rm some_pattern_*.txt`. Also `grep -v some_pattern_*.txt` has to be `grep -v 'some_pattern_*.txt'`, otherwise `*` will expand. And why `-v` - OP requested to delete `some_pattern_*.txt` files, not to delete all the other files. And [you should not parse ls output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). And `ssh` may be not available for OP, only `sftp`. Also please in such cases use `xargs -d$'\n'` - `xargs` parses `"` and `'` and \ and whitespaces spacially without delimeter.

Comment: Thank you. Actually OP don't want to delete some_pattern*txt

**!**ls some_pattern_*.txt > deletion_list.txt

hence grep -v . Yes. I should have provided string in quotes.